# Multiple `find_with_related()` in sea_orm

Tags: sql, select, rust, orm, sea-orm

Let's say I have a `parent::Entity` with zero or many `good_child::Entity`, `neutral_child::Entity`, and `evil_child::Entity`. (Just an example. The actual `child_*` tables have nothing in common with one another).

Each child has a field with its parent's id. Now I can select all good_children for some parent with

```rust
let (parent, good_children) = model::parent::Entity::find_by_id(42)
    .find_with_related(model::good_child::Entity)
    .all(&db.begin().await.map_err(…)?)
    .await
    .map_err(…)?
    .pop()
    .ok_or(…)?;
```

But how can I get the neutral and evil children in the same query? Simply adding another [`find_with_related()`](https://docs.rs/sea-orm/0.9.2/sea_orm/entity/prelude/struct.Select.html#method.find_with_related) call does not work:

> no method named `find_with_related` found for struct `SelectTwoMany` in the current scope
>
> method not found in `SelectTwoMany<…::parent::Entity, projektdb_model::good_child::Entity>`

Comment: See this https://github.com/SeaQL/sea-orm/discussions/1028.

Answer (score 0):

Please use custom select

```
pub struct AccountDTO {
    pub account_id: i64,
    pub role_name: Option<String>,
    pub email: Option<String>,
    pub phone: Option<String>,
    pub actived: bool,
    pub last_visited: Option<DateTime>,
    pub created_date: NaiveDateTime,
    pub updated_date: Option<DateTime>,
}


let accounts = match Account.find.filter(account::Column::Deleted.eq(false))
    .columns([
        account::Column::AccountId,
        account::Column::Phone,
        account::Column::Email,
        account::Column::Actived,
        account::Column::LastVisited,
        account::Column::CreatedDate,
        account::Column::UpdatedDate,
    ])
    .column_as(
        Expr::col((Alias::new("role_alias"), role::Column::RoleName)),
        "role_name"
    )
    .join_as(
        JoinType::LeftJoin,
        account::Relation::Role
            .def(),
        Alias::new("role_alias")
    )
    .offset(offset)
    .limit(limit)
    .into_model::<AccountDTO>()
    .all(db::get())
    .await
{
    Err(err) => {
        tracing::error!(error = ?err, "err find account");
        return Err(ApiErr::ErrSystem(Some(err.to_string())));
    }
    Ok(v) => v,
};
```

Comment: I think you answered how to do a self-referential query, but that's not what I was asking. Maybe to posted to the wrong question by accident?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question.